# Cannot read property 'address_1' of undefined - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a code like this

```
class EventDetails extends React.Component {
    constructor( props ) {
        super (props);
        this.state={
            startdate: props.startdate || "",
            enddate: props.enddate || "",
            venue: props.venue || ""
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch(`https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/venues/${this.state.venue}/?token=EventBrite'sTOKEN`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(eventvenue => this.setState({ venue: eventvenue }))
    }

    render() {
        const { startdate, enddate, venue } = this.state;
        const getDateWhenTheEventStart = new Date(Date.parse(startdate));
        const theDateWhenTheEventStart = getDateWhenTheEventStart.toDateString();
        const theHourWhenTheEventStart = getDateWhenTheEventStart.getHours();
        const theMinuteWhenTheEventStart = getDateWhenTheEventStart.getMinutes();

        const getDateWhenTheEventEnd = new Date(Date.parse(enddate));
        const theDateWhenTheEventEnd = getDateWhenTheEventEnd.toDateString();
        const theHourWhenTheEventEnd = getDateWhenTheEventEnd.getHours();
        const theMinuteWhenTheEventEnd = getDateWhenTheEventEnd.getMinutes();

        function checkTime(time) {
            if (time < 10) {
                time = '0' + time
            }
            return time;
        }

        return(
            <React.Fragment>
                <Container text>
                <Header as="h1">Date and Time</Header>
                    <p><strong>Starts:</strong> {theDateWhenTheEventStart} | {checkTime(theHourWhenTheEventStart)}:{checkTime(theMinuteWhenTheEventStart)}</p>
                    <p><strong>Ends:</strong> {theDateWhenTheEventEnd} | {checkTime(theHourWhenTheEventEnd)}:{checkTime(theMinuteWhenTheEventEnd)}</p>

                <Header as="h1">Location</Header>
                    <List>
                        <List.Item>{venue.name}</List.Item>
                        {venue.address.address_1 != undefined && <List.Item>{venue.address.address_1}</List.Item>}
                        {venue.address.localized_area_display != undefined && <List.Item>{venue.address.localized_area_display}</List.Item>}
                    </List>
                </Container>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}

export default EventDetails;
```

The problem of the code is here

```
{venue.address.address_1 != undefined && <List.Item>{venue.address.address_1}</List.Item>} // gives me the error of 'Cannot read property 'address_1' of undefined'
```

I suspect that this problem occured because the component render first and the program breaks because the state is not updated yet.

Do you have any ideas how to solve this problem? Thank you

Comment: can you please share the response of venue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that the `venue.address` is not null before using `venue.address.address_1`

`{venue.address && venue.address.address_1 !== undefined && <List.Item>{venue.address.address_1}</List.Item>}`

Answer (score 1):

You would have to do full error checking elsewhere - for example when you set the state.

But if you would like to do a one liner and do a full Error Check, following would be possible

```
<List>
    <List.item>Date and Time</List.item>
    {venue ? venue.address ? venue.address.address_1 ? <List.Item>{venue.address.address_1}</List.Item> : <List.Item>Loading..</List.Item> : <List.Item>Loading..</List.Item> : <List.Item>Loading..</List.Item>
</List>
```

However, as you can see, it's a very ugly way of doing it so do validity checking elsewhere if you want to use ternary

Answer (score 1):

This is the safest full check if your object is defined or not with all properies during rendering (I think the cleanest too). It will render element if your object is fully valid.

```
{!!venue && !!venue.address && !!venue.address.address_1 
   && <List.Item>{venue.address.address_1}</List.Item>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the best way of doing this is to use `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()` to check whether your object contains a particular key or not :

```
{venue.hasOwnProperty(address) && 
  venue.address.hasOwnProperty(address_1) && 
   <List.Item>{venue.address.address_1}</List.Item>}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's always a good idea to check than an object and all nested objects you want to access have loaded. Please find an example of how I would check. When using the && operator, Javascript will check for the first false statement and then stop. In other words, if venue is "" (an empty string is considered false), null, or undefined, Javascript will stop checking at venue, before an error similar to the one you posted above is thrown.

If venue exists, it will then check venue.address, and so on, until finally, it will return the last statement "{venue.address.address_1}". If you try the code below, you'll see what I mean.

One last thing - please make sure the venue props are actually being passed to your component, or the two List.Item components will not render (though you will not get an error).

```
            <List>
                {venue && venue.name && <List.Item>{venue.name}</List.Item>}
                {venue && venue.address && venue.address.address1 && <List.Item>{venue.address.address_1}</List.Item>}
                {venue && venue.address && venue.address.localized_area_display && <List.Item>{venue.address.localized_area_display}</List.Item>}
            </List>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check something like below

> {venue && venue.address && venue.address_1 ?  . 
>       {venue.address.address_1} : ''}

Here you can see, first we are checking if venue object is available then we check for the inner one and then nested object. This is the best practice instead of directly displaying the value. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of long checks like a && a.b && a.b.c, use *lodash get*.

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#get